# Dynamically binding Report to ReportViewer component

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, report

I want to show different reports in ReportViewer component, based on selected text in comboBox, but it seems I'm having difficulties binding data sources to reports.
This is the code in `comboBox.TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` handler

```
reportViewer.Reset();
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportViewer." + MapComboBoxItem2ReportName(cbReports.Text) + ".rdlc";
this.reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

I'm getting an error: "A data source instance has not been supplied for the datasource DataSet1".
What else do I need to do so I could load report dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

When you change the reportViewer's source report, you have also have to to set the datasources for it. Normally, the designer handles that for you (take a look at the designer generated code to see how it handles it), but changing the source report resets the LocalReport object of the control.

Therefore you need to supply all datasources to your report so that it can display correctly :

```
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportViewer." + MapComboBoxItem2ReportName(cbReports.Text) + ".rdlc";
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.Datasource.Add("Datasource1", whateverIsYourDatasourceObject)
this.reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

You have to add the same line for every datasource defined in your report. If you're not sure about the datasources names you need to use, look at the designer generated code to see what they are. You can also use the following code to find out all the report's datasources names :

```
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.GetDataSourceNames()
```

If your report has variables, you need to define them too, otherwise you'll get the same error.

Hope that helps

Comment: this is not working for me at all. There's some huge mistake I'm making and I think it has something to do with the process of creating new reports. Whenever I create a new Report, I'm using `"DataSet1"` as the DataSource. I don't know where to look anymore to solve this...

Comment: Without more details on your code, it's kind of hard to tell what the problem really is.

Answer (score 1):

you left out the **ReportPath**.

```
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports\\" + MapComboBoxItem2ReportName(cbReports.Text) + ".rdlc";

this.reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportViewer." + MapComboBoxItem2ReportName(cbReports.Text) + ".rdlc";

this.reportViewer.LocalReport.Datasource.Add("Datasource1", whateverIsYourDatasourceObject)
this.reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

Answer (score 0):

> A data source instance has not been supplied for the datasource
>   DataSet1

Please make sure first parameter name is "DataSet1". Which would be the one you created a new DataSource in .rdlc Design Form and named as "**DataSet1**".

```
this.reportViewr.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", 
                                           yourDataSet.Tables[0]));
```

Comment: Also, you'll have to identify the data to be provided to the report (based on report name, etc.) to make sure it's bound correctly.  Each report's expected data structure will most likely be different.

Comment: this is not working for me at all. There's some huge mistake I'm making and I think it has something to do with the process of creating new reports. Whenever I create a new Report, I'm using `"DataSet1"` as the DataSource. I don't know where to look anymore to solve this...